# Datatable : Ordering on two columns and then show only first 10 rows

Tags: datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using  ***DataTables 1.10.11*** version.

I have a requirement. I have almost 1000 data list. From that list I need to order on two columns by default and then need to show only first 10 rows.

Please help me to achieve this requirement.

Comment: "_Please help me to achieve this requirement._" - we cannot help you without code and an example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to implement this requirement.

```
$('#id').DataTable({
                dom : 't',
                "processing" : true,
                "deferRender" : true,
                "data" : data,
                "columns" : getColConfg(),
                "language" : {
                    "emptyTable" : "No data available"
                },
                "pageLength" : 10
                "order" : [ [ 2, "desc" ], [1, "desc"] ]
            });
```

> **dom : 't',**

Adding dom as 't' only served my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bPaginate": true,
        "sPaginationType": 'full_numbers',
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        columnDefs: [ {
            targets: [ 0 ],
            orderData: [ 0, 1 ]
        }]
    } );
} );
```